# Trigger a function with the help of Cron job and delete the data

Tags: node.js, firebase, cron, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created a function that uses cron job. I am using cron-job.org, Now I want to add a functionality that deletes the records.

For example,

It draws down in fetching the server timestamp and fetching the necessary data based on a date/time flag. If the timestamp (eg. hour) and the date/time flag matches, I can delete its data.

I have a record let's say Status in documents and there are many documents that contains this record yes all the documents are in one collection.I also have the expiry_date/time of each record that is status.

I am succeeded in triggering my function on hourly basis but I don't have any idea how can I fetch the expiry_date/time and matches it with timestamp when the function is triggered and delete the Status.

Please provide me the best possible approach.

Here is the code but this just triggered every hour and send the response

```
   exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     // [END trigger]
     // [START sendError]
     // Forbidding PUT requests.
     if (req.method === 'PUT') {
       return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
     }
     // [END sendError]

     // [START usingMiddleware]
     // Enable CORS using the `cors` express middleware.
     cors(req, res, () => {
       // [END usingMiddleware]
       // Reading date format from URL query parameter.
       // [START readQueryParam]
       let format = req.query.format;
       // [END readQueryParam]
       // Reading date format from request body query parameter
       if (!format) {
         // [START readBodyParam]
         format = req.body.format;
         // [END readBodyParam]
       }
       // [START sendResponse]
       const formattedDate = moment().format(format);
       console.log('Sending Formatted date:', formattedDate);
       res.status(200).send(formattedDate);
       // [END sendResponse]
     });
    })
```

My database structure is like this
[image: First half]
[image: Second half that shows all the status of perticular users]

Comment: The codes speaks more than words. Please edit your question and update it with the code that you've tried so far for the community to help you.

Comment: Sure..But that code just triggers every hour and get the current time that's all my friend\

Comment: What is the structure of the data you are trying to delete? What does you current trigger implementation look like? Add the json and code to your question.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of my database. i want to delete the Status when it reaches expiry_date/time

Comment: @Callam I have added the database screenshots please have a look..